# Windows 7 web browser cannot access localhost

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, mysql, xampp, sql

I'm using windows 7 and installed xampp, but I can't access localhost from all web browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox), it always give me "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

I already googling it and found many solution for the same case as mine but nothing works so far. this error occur after I changed my HDD.

I tried to ping 127.0.0.1 from cmd and it gives me reply but when I tried it form chrome it gives me connection error message

Comment: Did you reinstall XAMPP after replacing your HDD?

Comment: just try to `ping localhost` to see if you can lookup localhost as 127.0.0.1, if you can , then `telnet localhost 80` to check if xampp is working on port 80 (or other port  that u are using)

Comment: @kirelagin yap, already tried different version too

Comment: @BiloChan it gives me this answer "Connecting to localhost...could not open connection to the host, on port 80 : connect failed"

Comment: Just make sure your xampp is working and listening on port 80, if so, you check with `netstat -ano` there should be a record like `TCP    0.0.0.0:80            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       xxx`, do you have it?

Comment: @BiloChan heres come the real problem, I was always unable to start apache service from xampp control panel or windows task manager, but before i changed and reinstall my hdd it never be a problem and my localhost can works properly although my apache can't be started, i've tried to change the port from 80 to 81, 82, 83 or another port, yet i still get the same result..

Comment: I am not familiar with xampp much but I think there should be a log file that you can find out why xampp can't be started. However, have to tried to reinstall xampp? It is not hard to retain the data, just some "copy and paste" work

Comment: @BiloChan i tried it, with different version too, but it doesn't solve anything

Answer (score 0):

Though I came here in search of help with a different Web server (Apache 2.4), the diagnostic suggestions enabled me to identify and correct the cause of my problem. It seems that `httpd -k install` installs, but doesn't **start** the service. For that, you need `net start Apache2.4`.

Once that command completes, SysInternals utility `pslist64.exe` displays the expected two httpd processes, while `netstat -ano` reports that the first of the two is listening on ports **443** (SSL/TLS) and **80** (HTTP). While I have yet to see the desired Web page, I can tell, by the fact that I have a HTTP Forbidden error page, that my browser sees the Web server on localhost.